# WNDCLASSEX vs WNDCLASSEXW?

Tags: c++, winapi

I've searched high and low on Google. I see information regarding window classes and WNDCLASSEX here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633577%28v=vs.85%29.aspx but I don't see anything about WNDCLASSEXW. What's the difference? Why would I use one over the other? Where can I find documentation?

I take that back. The only thing I see is: WNDCLASSEXW (Unicode) and WNDCLASSEXA (ANSI) but I have no idea what that means besides Unicode being a character encoding standard.

EDIT: Chris nailed it. See the link he provided. "Many Windows API functions have "A" (ANSI) and "W" (wide, Unicode) versions. The "A" version handles text based on Windows code pages, while the "W" version handles Unicode text."

This thread should definitely be helpful for anyone inevitably googling the same thing in the future, lol.

Comment: It means anything to do with strings in `WNDCLASSEXW` expects a UTF-16 string, whereas `WNDCLASSEXA` expects an ANSI string. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd317752.aspx

Comment: Brilliant, thanks a ton. I knew someone would pull through!